# How to remove actions from Yoast SEO plugin

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I need to remove the actions that Yoast SEO has added. This is my code:

```
function remove_actions() {

// deregister all not more required tags
    remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 50 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'test123' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'front_page_specific_init' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'head' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'head' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'metadesc' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'robots' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'metakeywords' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'canonical' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'adjacent_rel_links' ), 50 );
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'publisher' ), 50 );

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_actions', 1000 );
```

This code does not remove the actions.  What is wrong? How can I remove the actions successfully?

Comment: I edit the source code of yoast seo and add action test123, when I try to remove it by this function it not works and test123 still show in source code on my page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these notes from the [remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) Documentation:

> 1. You may need to prioritize the removal of the action to a hook that occurs after the action is added.
> 2. You cannot successfully remove the action before it has been added.
> 3. You also cannot remove an action after it has been run.
> 4. To remove an action the priority must match the priority with with the function was originally added.

In your case, I believe several of these issues (especially #3 and #4) are causing problems:

First, the priority on your `add_action` is too high.  By setting it this high, it's running *after* all of the Yoast `wp_head` actions are run.  Instead, hook into the same action you want to remove, but with a very *low* number, such as -99999, to cause it to run *before* the Yoast actions are run.  (Further, I've broken into two functions, just to *be sure* they are run at the correct time - one for each action - `wp_head` and `wpseo_head`).

Second, your priorities do not match the priorities in the Yoast code.  I've dug through all the Yoast code to find all of these actions and documented / corrected in the code below - and I can tell you for example the `metakeywords` hook in Yoast code is 11, so your remove_action (with priority 40) will not work.

Finally, Yoast adds these actions to `$this` (an instantiated version of the WPSEO_Frontend class), not static version of the class methods.  This means that `remove_action` is not able to find them based on the function array(`WPSEO_Frontend`, `head`), for example.   Instead, you need to load the instantiated version of Yoast, and pass *that* in to the `remove_action` functions.

Documented code below:

```
// Remove ONLY the head actions.  Permits calling this at a "safe" time
function remove_head_actions() {
    // not Yoast, but WP default. Priority is 1
    remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );

    // If the plugin isn't installed, don't run this!
    if ( ! is_callable( array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'get_instance' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the WPSEO_Frontend instantiated class
    $yoast = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
    // removed your "test" action - no need
    // per Yoast code, this is priority 0
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $yoast, 'front_page_specific_init' ), 0 );
    // per Yoast code, this is priority 1
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $yoast, 'head' ), 1 );
}

function remove_wpseo_head_actions() {
    // If the Yoast plugin isn't installed, don't run this
    if ( ! is_callable( array( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'get_instance' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the Yoast instantiated class
    $yoast = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $yoast, 'head' ), 50 );
    // per Yoast code, this is priority 6
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $yoast, 'metadesc' ), 6 );
    // per Yoast code, this is priority 10
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $yoast, 'robots' ), 10 );
    // per Yoast code, this is priority 11
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $yoast, 'metakeywords' ), 11 );
    // per Yoast code, this is priority 20
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $yoast, 'canonical' ), 20 );
    // per Yoast code, this is priority 21
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $yoast, 'adjacent_rel_links' ), 21 );
    // per Yoast code, this is priority 22
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $yoast, 'publisher' ), 22 );
}
```

**Final Notes:**.

Remove the WPSEO_Frontend::head action is **very heavy handed**.  This will yank a whole host of other things you probably don't want removed.

Second, It's probably *better* to modify the *output* of these actions, rather than removing them completely.

For example,

```
add_action('wpseo_metakeywords', 'your_metakeywords_function');

function your_metakeywords_function( $keywords ) {
    // modify the keywords as desired
    return $keywords;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Needed to remove Yoast from 1 document. Your answer was very helpful!

Comment: wpseo_metakeywords sadly is depreceated without alternative since Version 6.3
Just leaving this here for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Many of these actions have filters and output can be removed by returning `false`.

```
// Removes 'meta name="description"' tag from output

add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'my_custom_metadesc' );

function my_custom_metadesc() {
  return false;
}
```

In some cases like WPSEO_Opengraph there's a filter pattern: wpseo_og_ + property name with underscores instead of colons.

```
// Filters '<meta property="article:tag" content="Foo" />'

add_filter( 'wpseo_og_article_tag', 'my_custom_article_tag' );
```