# How can I hook into Woocommerce plugin extensions from my themes function.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to move the Amazon Pay message/button on the checkout page in Woocommerce. We are using Amazon Pay by Woocommerce.

When I look at the plugin code I have determined that in the plugin's file /woocommerce-gateway-amazon-payments-advanced.php the message/button gets added using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array( $this, 'checkout_message' ), 5 );
```

From my functions.php file I have tried multiple ways to remove this action:

I thought this would work:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array( 'WC_Amazon_Payments_Advanced', 'checkout_message' ), 5 );
```

I feel like I am missing something simple here.

How can I remove this action?

Comment: You are missing two things!  1. _timing_.  Your functions.php file is most likely running _before_ the add_action is being set, which means you're removing an action that hasn't been added yet.  2. In your remove action, you are passing in the _static_ class name, but the action is added on `$this` - the instantiated version of the class.  This is something I answered recently here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235875/how-to-remove-actions-from-yoast-seo-plugin/48241337#48241337

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove actions from Yoast SEO plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235875/how-to-remove-actions-from-yoast-seo-plugin)

Comment: I answered this question over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715615/move-amazon-button-on-woocommerce-checkout-page